# highchart not displaying when the script is called second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to load highchart dynamically using the following script

```
if (typeof window.Highcharts == "undefined") {
    alert("1")
    $.holdReady(true);
    $.getScript("js/highcharts.js", function() {
        $.holdReady(false);
    });
} else {
    alert("2");
}
```

when i load the tab first time it gives me alert with value 1 and graph is loaded but when user click on the tab second time alert gives the value 2 but the script throws an error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function" and highchart is also not plotted

Comment: Could you create a minimal example, e.g. in JSFiddle?

Comment: Sounds like you need to check for the existence of Highcharts, and not load it a second time if it's already loaded.